# Resource not found when loading images which names depends on AngularJS variable

Tags: angularjs

I use AngularJS in my website and some images are loaded like this:

```
<img ng-cloak src="{{ person.username }}"/>
```

the problem is that I get 404 errors in console that the image is not found because before angular is laoded it tries to load image named `{{ person.username }}`

How do I solve this?

Comment: Change src to ng-src.
According to angular:
Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

```
 <img ng-cloak ng-src="{{ person.username }}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use :

**ng-src**

**Example :**

```
<img ng-cloak ng-src="{{ person.username }}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the browser tries to load the resource before the expression is evaluated by angular.
That's why there are build in directives as ng-href or ng-src that should be used.